# larger image on hover - CSS3 Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, opacity, webkit-transform

does anybody know how to get this

```
img.resizableImage:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
    -o-transform:scale(1.5);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

working in Internet Explorer?

Already using the normalize css!

Thanks!

Comment: Simply change the height and width of image like `img.resizable:hover{width:10%;height:10%;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your other transform properties are browser specific.

For IE9+:

```
-ms-transform: scale(1.5);
```

Comment: Well it works in IE11 but not in IE10 and lower... may you know why?